# Apache & TomCat & SSL - App Not Working

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ssl, rhel5

At this moment i have Apache & Tomcat running in a RHEL server of one our clients.
What he asks for is that in the same server/machine (its a QUA server) we have 4 websites (all the same)
Example:

> http:// hostname   http:// hostname.domain.com      https:// hostname
>         https:// hostname.domain.com

Where the http redirects to a Institutional Page and the https redirects to an Aplication page (/servlet/CO)

Where the Apache handles the http, and redirects the https to the TomCat.

The problem is that i can make it work (institutional page and app page) for 1 http and 1 https.
But if i put the 4 of them working, the Aplication returns an JavanullpointException when loading.

And i don't know if its motivated by the redirecting of the hostnames/ip/fqdn made in /etc/hosts and ssl.conf and the app simply doesnt handle these configurations.

Or if i'm doing something wrong.

The only significant alterations made, was adding in the SSL.Conf the

> < location >Web-INF< /location >...etc

I don't know if you can help. Im aware of the lack of information that i cant provide.

Thank you

Edit: Totally forgot

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
      at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:199)
      at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:236)
      at ▒.▒sg.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at ▒.▒sg.▒a(Unknown Source)
      at ▒.▒w0.▒a(Unknown Source)
      at ▒.▒x0.doGet(Unknown Source)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:210)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:151)
      at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:200)
      at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
      at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:775)
      at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:704)
      at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:897)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:685)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
```

Comment: if you can see that an NullPointer is thrown, it would help if you could post a stacktrace

Comment: Edited The Initial Post.
Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the information you have given is quite limited, but `StringTokenizer` is getting a `null` argument here:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
      at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:199)
      at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(StringTokenizer.java:236)
      at ▒.▒sg.<init>(Unknown Source) <----- HERE
      at ▒.▒sg.▒a(Unknown Source)
      at ▒.▒w0.▒a(Unknown Source)
      at ▒.▒x0.doGet(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Stupid doubt.
Those ▒.▒ are the problem, or is just random caracthers without relevance?

Comment: i thought it was obfuscated since you did not want to show your company name?

Comment: no. the catalina.out returns the error like that. :/

Comment: you are going to have the ask the application developers to assist, I suspect they are intercepting the stack trace and adding that.